# How to get other user's info from Oura Ring API?

Tags: python, api

I am integrating [Oura Ring API](https://cloud.ouraring.com/docs/) to python.
I can get my info from the API.
But I can not get any other user's information.
If someone has idea about it please help me.

Comment: Would it be possible  to elaborate more? A snippet or example of what is working  and what is not.

Comment: I created an app on my oura account and so I have client_id and secret_key. I can get my personal data from API but I need to get my partner's data. But I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Ignore my comment below, you do know to create an app.  Were you able to use the oauth flow to get your partner authorized for you to download?  For your purpose of 1 person, easier to have them make a personal token, so you can avoid all the oauth machinery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Oura Ring](https://ouraring.com/) provides secure [API](https://cloud.ouraring.com/docs/) to access user information. This means that
User information is made available using access token for each user.

Here is an example GET call
eg:
https://api.ouraring.com/v1/userinfo?access_token=PHCW3OVMXQZX5FJUR6ZK4FAA2MK2CWWA

So if one wants information for any other user, an authorised Personal Access Token for that user can be used to get the info.

Each user can create a Personal Access Token here :
https://cloud.ouraring.com/personal-access-tokens

Use this personal access token in your application to fetch the information for each user by making calls to API as follows (in your browser address bar):

https://api.ouraring.com/v1/userinfo?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_OF_YOUR_ACCOUNT

https://api.ouraring.com/v1/userinfo?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_OF_YOUR_PARTNERS_ACCOUNT

Here is the API documentation on Personal Information Token (Scroll to bottom of page):

https://cloud.ouraring.com/docs/authentication

This is how you can try/test your access tokens on client side (in postman) :
https://medium.com/@lserafin/exploring-the-oura-cloud-api-with-postman-4d1c4abcd888

Here is a tutorial on how to create a server side application in Python ( Note this uses Application Authentication and not Personal Access Token - this may not solve your problem but might give you some ideas).

https://medium.com/@pgzmnk/build-a-sleep-tracking-app-using-oura-part-1-interface-the-oura-cloud-api-cf71a3b981d6

Comment: How can I get ACCESS_TOKEN_OF_YOUR_ACCOUNT of all user?

Comment: https://cloud.ouraring.com/personal-access-tokens This will give you the access token for a given user. I am afraid API does not publish the list of all the users.

Comment: @yagocanepa : this is protected personal data.  You can not get a list of all users nor access to their data!  You can ask people to create personal tokens to share with you.  Or you can register an app in oura and have users opt in to sharing with your app.  Apps limited to 10 people until reviewed and approved.